# how to add number of rows in detailView dynamically in yii2

Tags: yii2, detailview

```
$dataProviderDetails = new ActiveDataProvider([

                 'query'=> $details
                            ->select(['pk_int_particular_id','vchr_particular_name','int_amount'])
                            ->from('tbl_payroll_details')
                            ->join( 'INNER JOIN', 'tbl_salary_particular', 'tbl_salary_particular.pk_int_particular_id = tbl_payroll_details.fk_salary_particular_id')
                            ->where(['fk_int_payroll_id'=> $id])
                            ->All(),
                            ]);


        $payroll = $dataProviderDetails->query;    
        return $this->render('view', [
               //'model' => $model, 
               'payroll' => $payroll  
        ]);
```

this join contain the result set is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pk_int_particular_id] => 1 [vchr_particular_name] => basicSalary [int_amount] => 10000 ) [1] => Array ( [pk_int_particular_id] => 2 [vchr_particular_name] => HRA [int_amount] => 200 ) [2] => Array ( [pk_int_particular_id] => 3 [vchr_particular_name] => PA [int_amount] => 500 ) [3] => Array ( [pk_int_particular_id] => 4 [vchr_particular_name] => professionaltax [int_amount] => 1000 ) )
```

I printed result in detailView like `$payroll[0][vchr_particular_name]`

but I would like to know how can I add number of rows in detailView dynamically using array index. Is it possible?

Comment: you mean the total count of selected rows ?

Comment: yea total count should be the number of rows

Comment: i have already posted  and answer  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the total count of the rows select you could use **count()** instead of all in your query

```
->select(['pk_int_particular_id', 'vchr_particular_name', 'int_amount'])
  ->from('tbl_payroll_details')
  ->join( 'INNER JOIN',  'tbl_salary_particular',  'tbl_salary_particular.pk_int_particular_id = tbl_payroll_details.fk_salary_particular_id')
  ->where(['fk_int_payroll_id'=> $id])
  ->count()
```

but remember that in an **activeDataProvider** this should be already calculated by the object itself and store in the '**totalCount**' property or you can get it using **getTotalCount()** method of **activeDataProvider**

```
 $dataProviderDetails->totalCount;
 $dataProviderDetails->getTotalCount();
```

Comment: yes your right. but in <?= DetailView::widget([]) ?> where i set the count to print the fixed records, Suppose  if array return 5 rows then detailView's rows should be 5, 0r 8 rows it should be 8,   which propery of detailView should i want to set the total count? i think you unserstanda problem...

Comment: . you have the value  in dataProvider .so you can print pratically where you prefer ... see here for some suggestion http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html

Comment: thnksss @scaisEdge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625654/how-to-display-default-value-in-dropdownlist  @scaisEdge please check this question